# Destination IP for port 443 (HTTPs)

Tags: networking, https, openssl, firewall

We are running a Java based web-application, and were in the process of updating the site from http:// to https:// (by installing SSL cert),but encountered issues with bringing the site online.

On further analysis, we found that the port 443 was being blocked, which was preventing this site from being accessible on https://

We informed the same to the Network team, to open firewall on port 443. But the problem is, they keep coming back asking for the destination port.

We provided the source IP (IP of the application server)...what would be the destination IP (is there a specific destination IP if a site needs to be accessible on https://) ????

My question is, what would be the destination port, to open firewall to make a site accessible on https:// ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely they want to setup NAT so that incoming requests coming to NAT:443 are routed to :443 , and for this they do need an IP of the server within the local network.